# How to fix list numbering indent in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I am having problems with the list numbering in Word.

Whilst there are some 'solutions' online and here they do not work for me. As you can see, the common solution : 'Set left- and first-indent with tabs and backspaces' is already set.

Strangely, the numbering does work correctly in the list above (but it leaves strange spaces) but refuses to work in the same way in the list below. I have tried different things but it does not want to indent in the list below, only increasing the numbering indent 3.1.x... on TAB instead.

Can anyone please help?

[image: Screenshot]